# getImageData to detect colour-collision isn't working

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, for-loop, html5-canvas

I'm trying to write a getImageData, so whenever my car hits the black part of the track, there's an alert. However, it is not working, as the car keeps going.

Could someone please help me figure out the getImageData array and possibly fix up my code?

```
//Setting the canvas and context
    var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //Uploading car
    var car = new Image();
    car.src = "file:///H:/Desktop/Game/img/car.png";

    //Setting properties of car
    var x = 450;
    var y = 730;
    var speed = 10;
    var angle = 990;
    var mod = 0;

    //Event listeners for keys
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keypress_handler, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyup_handler, false);

    //Interval for animation
    var moveInterval = setInterval(function () {
        draw();
    }, 30);

    //Drawing the car turning and changing speed
    function draw() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        x += (speed * mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
        y += (speed * mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle);

        context.save();
        context.translate(x, y);
        context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * angle);
        context.drawImage(car, -(car.width / 2), -(car.height / 2));
        context.restore();
    }

    //Setting the keys
    function keyup_handler(event) {
        console.log('a');
        if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) {

            mod = 0;
        }
    }

    //Setting all of the keys
    function keypress_handler(event) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            mod = 1;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            mod = -1;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            angle -= 5;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            angle += 5;
        }
    }

    //INSERT COLOUR DETECTION CODE TEST
    (function () {
        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
        window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
    })();

    function collideTest(){
        var stopColour = context.getImageData(x - 5, y - 5,60,60);
        for (var i = 0; i < stopColour.data.length; i += 4) {
            if (stopColour.data[i] == 190707) {
                alert("black");
            }
        }
    }

    function render(){

        var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var car = new Image();
        car.src = "file:///H:/Desktop/Game/img/car.png";

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imagedata array is an array where each entry is a value between 0 and 255 (4 array entries represent one RGBA pixel). I don't know how exactly you came up with the number 190707, but `stopColour.data[i] == 190707` will never be `true`, because you won't encounter values above 255 in the array.

When you want to check for a match with a specific color on all three color channels, you need to check three values.

```
var collision_red = // red-part of your collision color between 0 and 255
var collision_green = // green-part of your collision color between 0 and 255
var collision_blue = // blue-part of your collision color between 0 and 255

// ...

if ( stopColour.data[i + 0] == collision_red &&
     stopColour.data[i + 1] == collision_green &&
     stopColour.data[i + 2] == collision_blue ) {

     // collision
}
```

By the way: Instead of relying on color-keying, it is often much more robust and performance friendly to check for invisible geometric shapes for overlap ("bounding boxes" or "bounding circles").

Comment: Would you make create rectangles on their own and then bound with Element.getBoundingClientRect?

Comment: @SasukeRinnegan No, I would define a rectangle for each object in the game and then check for collisions by checking their coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not *directly* related to your issue, but pertinent in the light of the stated problem centring upon using getImageData() for collision detection, a task I have recently been attempting also. If future updates of your project include using translated coordinates, then this will become *immediately* relevant.

A warning has to be issued about using getImageData() and putImageData() on an HTML5 canvas. Which centres upon using translated coordinates via the translate() method.

While most of the drawing methods use the resulting translated coordinate system, getImageData() and putImageData() **DO NOT** use that translated coordinate system, but instead **always** use the standard coordinate system, with (0, 0) located at the top left hand corner of your canvas! I discovered this the hard way, trying to use getImageData() for a simple collision detection algorithm, and wondered why, during testing, selecting coordinates that were *known* to be part of a rendered image on the canvas, returned pixel values of [0, 0, 0, 0], instead of the true pixel values. This happened because the translated coordinate system was being used to reference the pixels in question. When the coordinates were altered to those that would have applied in the standard coordinate system, the desired data was correctly detected.

However, to add to the confusion, drawImage() **DOES** use translated coordinates when these are set using translate()!

If seemingly weird data appears in the return object from getImageData(), when implementing a translated coordinate system using translate(), this is the reason. Which means that the coordinates of the *translated* origin of the canvas in the *standard* coordinate system, must be saved, and those saved original coordinates added to coordinate values from the *translated* coordinate system. Here's a very simple test illustrating this:

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="MyCanvas" width="401" height="401" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border: 1px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);">

</body>

<script language="JavaScript">

//Get my canvas handle and 2d plotting context ...

myCanvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
myCanvasCtx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

//Get the centre of your canvas in standard coordinates
//with (0, 0) at the top left hand corner ...

cx = Math.floor(myCanvas.width/2);
cy = Math.floor(myCanvas.height/2);

//Translate the origin for drawing to this central position ...

myCanvasCtx.translate(cx, cy);

//Do some image plotting here, using your new translated coordinates ... for this quick example,
//I'll simply plot some pixels using the usual path routines ...

tx = 0;    //origin AFTER translation, which is now in the centre
ty = 0;    //of the canvas

myCanvasCtx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)";    //set magenta foreground colour

myCanvasCtx.beginPath();
myCanvasCtx.moveTo(tx, ty);
myCanvasCtx.lineTo(tx + 1, ty);
myCanvasCtx.lineTo(tx + 1, ty + 1);
myCanvasCtx.lineTo(tx, ty + 1);
myCanvasCtx.lineTo(tx, ty);
myCanvasCtx.stroke();

//Now look at what happens if you try using your translated coordinates with getImageData():

wrongData = myCanvasCtx.getImageData(tx, ty, 1, 1);

txt = "Wrong data using translated coordinates of centre :";
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
 txt += wrongData.data[i].toString()+" ";

alert(txt);

//On the other hand, you should see data corresponding to magenta pixels if you do this:

rightData = myCanvasCtx.getImageData(tx + cx, ty + cy, 1, 1);

txt = "Right data using standard coordinates of centre :";
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
 txt += rightData.data[i].toString()+" ";

alert(txt);

</script>

</html>
```

When the above simple test is run, the first alert will give pixel data of [0, 0, 0, 0], corresponding to the transparent data at the top right hand corner of the screen, whilst the second alert will yield the correct data for the plotted magenta pixels at the centre of the canvas. Note that those expecting [255, 0, 255, 255], will actually see something like [255, 0, 255, 239] instead, and changing the line caps doesn't seem to affect this.